# Force old (Plone3) date time formats in Plone 4

Tags: datetime, plone

I want to force (ignore the locales) for the Language files in Plone 4. After a bunch of googling and source code reading I found [an old bug-report](https://dev.plone.org/ticket/11171) that people have the same issue as I had.

While reading this I noticed that they created/modified [the i18nl10n.py](https://github.com/plone/Products.CMFPlone/blob/master/Products/CMFPlone/i18nl10n.py#L101) file. When you look at line 101 I you see that they check if the Products.CMFPlone.i18nl10n.override_dateformat.Enabled checkbox is enabled that it will use the registery values to configure the language settings.

Thus I've done this and expected this to work, but (alas) it did not.
My Configuration Registery looks like the following:[image: configuration_registery]

However the time is still shown in American notation:
[image: rpm_with_dt_notation]

I have tried to refresh, restart and rerun. Yet nothing seems to yield any result.

Comment: Can you show us the related code of the table? I mean how do you insert the date into the table?

Comment: @Mathias this is the default plone table. for file listings.

Comment: Okey, didn't use such default plone listings for a long time :-)

Comment: Are you able to debug? I mean are you able to get this brain in a debug session? or place a break point at the right place?

Comment: @Mathias as it is the default view I have NO clue where to put the import ipdb.

Comment: Did you try the lates plone 4 release, 4.3.3?

Comment: @Mathias I run:
•Plone 4.3.2 (4307)
•CMF 2.2.7
•Zope 2.13.21
•Python 2.6.8 (unknown, Jan 26 2013, 14:35:25) [GCC 4.7.2]
•PIL 1.7.8 (Pillow)